# JSF fetch value from dynamic created MenuItems

Tags: java, jsf

due to requirements of dynamic menu list I implemented it using Java code.
I put this into `p:menubar model=""`. The MenuItems are simple Pair objects, just two Strings, first one is `name` and the second `fileNamePath` which indicates a filepath to include when it's clicked by user. How can I retrieve this value in the same xhtml file where I put my menubar?

```
  <ui:define name="content">
        <p:panel style="margin-bottom:20px">
                <p:menubar model="#{mainPanel.model}">
                </p:menubar>
            <ui:include src="${}"/>??
        </p:panel>
    </ui:define>
```

Comment: The documentation of primefaces is quite comprehensive. What did you try so far? https://www.primefaces.org/documentation/  -  https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menu.xhtml

Comment: I tried with 2 repeats, then got lass com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat cannot be cast to class org.primefaces.model.menu.MenuElement (com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat and org.primefaces.model.menu.MenuElement are in unnamed module of loader 'app') because of submenuitem doesn't delegate rendering

Comment: The question is not clear enough for me.. but I think you want to render different views from using the same xhtml file, is it?

Comment: The PrimeFaces documentation and showcase also have an example how to programatically create a menu. ui:repeat is not part of it... [mcve] please. And why do you need to 'read' the value (whatever the value is)?